# ArangoDB Performance

Tags: docker, arangodb

I am exploring the use of Arangodb as a graph engine for a project I am working on that needs shortest path analysis.

My collections look like this:

- a route network of ~3.5M edges in an edge collection (_to/_from)
- a vertex collection ~2.7M vertices (geo index on [lat,lng]).
- a trips collection with start/end locations (not mapped to nodes).

The first task is to snap the origin and destination coordinates of the trips to vertices in on the network. I am using the following query to do that:

```
FOR t IN trips
    let snappedFrom = (
        FOR x IN nodes
          SORT GEO_DISTANCE([t.Orig_Long, t.Orig_Lat], [x.lng, x.lat]) ASC
          LIMIT 1
          RETURN x._id
        )[0]
    let snappedTo = (
        FOR x IN nodes
          SORT GEO_DISTANCE([t.Dest_Long, t.Dest_Lat], [x.lng, x.lat]) ASC
          LIMIT 1
          RETURN x._id
        )[0]
    UPDATE t._key WITH {snappedFrom,snappedTo} IN trips
```

This is taking around 3.5 hours, and I want to reduce that significantly if possible.

I am running on an AWS instance with 32GB of RAM and 8 cores. I notice that when running this query, it is only using a single core which is killing me.

I am curious about setting up the arangodb for pure performance. My use case is using the DB as a calculator really. In fact is likely it will be part of a CI/CD workflow when done. I don't need any safe guards in there, there wont be any parallel user requests, and if the data is bad, I just blow it away and start again.

I am using a standard install with docker

```
docker run -it --name=adb --rm -p 8528:8528 -v arangodb:/data -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock arangodb/arangodb-starter --starter.address=<$IP> --starter.mode=single
```

I am going to run into the same issue when I run `shortest_path` on all trips too, that will take forever if single core.

Any help with the config, better query, or even better AWS setups would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Someone mentioned the use of DISTANCE instead of GEO_DISTANCE, but it made little to no difference

Comment: It was also suggested to create a simple script to schedule multiple queries (one for each CPU) as each query runs in its own CPU. Simple as scheduling trip_count/cpu_count to each query with a LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 0):

add [Geo-Spatial Indexes](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/indexing-geo.html)
 on `Orig` and `Dest` fields, that will enable server to optimize / speed up sub-queries

for further speeding up of processing run main query in batches, processing more smaller batches is faster than running over all documents at once

Comment: I can't see why indexes on the looping collection would help but I will give it try, however surely any optimiser worth its salt is capable of batching that query for me. There is no way I am doing that task manually. It means I have to know the hardware (CPU count) I am running on etc. That's crazy. Though I totally agree it would work.

Comment: check the [Query for Sorted Results near Origin](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/indexing-geo.html#query-for-sorted-results-near-origin-near-type-query), it's exactly your use case